# Tense of the verb

Tags: tenses

The boss with his colleagues have reached the hall.

In the above sentence why do we use "have reached" instead of "has reached". I used to think that "boss with his colleagues " can be taken as singular?

Comment: TBH I'd use either 'The boss *and* his colleagues have reached the hall' or 'The boss has reached the hall with his colleagues'. 'The boss with his colleagues have reached the hall' sounds pretty awkward, it feels as though something's wrong with the word order

Answer (score 2):

That doesn’t seem right to me. If it were ‘The boss and his colleagues’ then yes, ‘have’ is correct. But the subject of your sentence is just the boss, so ‘has’ is correct. Think of it this way: you could rearrange the sentence into ‘The boss has reached the hall, with his colleagues.’

So ‘The boss, with his colleagues, has reached the hall’, is surely correct.

Edit: accidentally put ‘object’ in place of ‘subject’

Answer (score -2):

***With*** is a preposition.

It has some meanings including 
"a function word to indicate combination, accompaniment, presence, or addition".
(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/with)

It means "more than one".

So we should use the **plural** verb form here.